# VSCODE font change in editor

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the VScode editor font, but it is not reflecting. Please the images.

EDIT: I am on Ubuntu-20.

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Did you download and install it? [Here the instructions:](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work on Linux or MacOS, not all fonts may work. Try to look for another fonts what are working on your system or try to install some missed fonts.

Comment: Thanks i was on ubuntu and this font not there.

Comment: @raju If the issue was that the font wasn't installed, then this isn't the answer.